# Difference between "file:///" and "file://"

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

I tried both and both did the same. Is there any difference (only for interest)?

I have a WebView that loads local data and was able to hand over an URL like that.

Example:

```
webView.loadUrl("file://storage/emulated/0/folder1/folder2/hello.html"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the spec `file://storage/emulated/0/folder1/folder2/hello.html` is invalid. `storage` here should represent a host name.

While using the [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) you may choose to ignore the host that represents a path. This is described on the wiki page, which I quote below.

> A file URI takes the form of

**file://host/path**

> where host is the fully qualified domain name of the system on which
>   the path is accessible, and path is a hierarchical directory path of
>   the form directory/directory/.../name. If host is omitted, it is taken
>   to be "localhost", the machine from which the URL is being
>   interpreted. Note that when omitting host, the slash is not omitted
>   ("file:///foo.txt" is valid, while "file://foo.txt" is not, although
>   some interpreters manage to handle the latter).

My guess is that webView.loadUrl is lenient and accepts file URIs that do not conform to the spec. [Uri.fromFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile(java.io.File)) also provides an example on the right format.

> Example: "file:///tmp/android.txt"

Answer (score 4):

The difference in URL definiton in which the schema separated from the path using `schema://`. The next you specify the path, if the path is absolute then it begins with `/`.
The correct url on Unix

```
"file:///storage/emulated/0/folder1/folder2/hello.html"
```

but it could be on Windows

```
"file://c:/storage/emulated/0/folder1/folder2/hello.html"
```

Answer (score 2):

`file://` is a URL prefix, just like `http://` or `https://`.

If you have three slashes, then the file path will be `/storage/emulated/...` instead of just `storage/emulated/...` if you have only two slashes.

The former looks for the folder called `storage` in the `/` folder (the root folder) and continues from there.

The latter *should* look for a folder called `storage` in the working directory and continue from there. I'm not sure why it doesn't.