# How to connect to local git repo on another disk?

Tags: git, ssh, cmd, git-remote

I have a local source git repo `C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git\` and a local blank repo `D:\syb\loc`.

I want to add `srcmd.git` as a remote repo in `loc`. The adding seems to work:

```
D:\syb\loc master ❯ git remote add origin "C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git\"
D:\syb\loc master ❯ git remote -v
origin  C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git" (fetch)
origin  C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git" (push)
```

But `git remote show` and `git fetch origin` give the same error:

```
D:\syb\loc master ❯ git remote show origin
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Can you give some advice on how to solve this?**

My system: Windows 10

My terminal: Command Prompt in Windows Terminal, the master thing in user prompt is added by clink and oh-my-posh extensions to work with git.

This problem doesn't exist when I try to add it to remote reference in a git folder in `C:\SOMELOCATION`.

Comment: it should not have a trailing slash after the `.git`. Git origin expects a URL, not a file path.

Comment: it's just an issue with the syntax you use to point at the directory. Try something like: `file://C:/Users/qweta/Documents/scrmd.git/` or ``file:///C/Users/qweta/Documents/scrmd.git/``

Comment: These methods do work but the first one of @LeGEC 's. Thank you guys!

Comment: But I wonder why this is not a problem when the source directory and the destination directory are in the same disk, namely the `C:\` disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with the syntax for remote urls:

with `C:\User\...` (a string starting with no protocol prefix and a `<server>:...` pattern), `git` interprets this as an ssh url to a server named `C`.

One possible fix is to explicitly write a `file://...` url, something like :

```
file://C:/User/qweta/Documents/scrmd.git/
# or
file:///C/Users/qweta/Documents/scrmd.git/
```

---

I do not have a windows system at hand to confirm the following:

- git may also accept:

```
/C/User/qweta/Documents/scrmd.git
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tested all these methods again, all works except for the last one. Maybe I made a mistake earlier today when testing the `file://` method. And for later reference for other folks, check this answer for more details: [Difference between "file:///" and "file://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354048/difference-between-file-and-file)

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking :) I deleted the one that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

> But I wonder why this is not a problem when the source directory and the destination directory are in the same disk, namely the `C:` disk?

Your remote ends up with an extra trailing `"`

```
origin  C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git"
                                         ^^^
```

That is because Git bash has escaped the trailing double-quote when interpreting `\"`:

```
git remote add origin "C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git\"
                                                         ^^^
```

While this would have worked:

```
git remote add origin "C:\Users\qweta\Documents\scrmd.git\\"
                                                         ^^^
```

This is only if scrmd.git is a folder representing a bare repository, and even then, you would not need the trailing `\` anyway.

As commented, using a file protocol URL scheme `file://C:/Users/qweta/Documents/scrmd.git/` is also an even more valid solution.

Comment: Good perspective! Miserably, I didn't even notice this trailing `"`, lmao.

Comment: What if I have a repository on a Windows machine on a local network? On that machine I have initialized a bare repo, `C:\gameland.git`. On my dev machine, I tried `git remote add <remotename> <username>@<ipaddress>:/C:/gameland.git` and all variation of that I can think. It gives ` ''/C:/gameland.git'' does not appear to be a git repository`. I'm not using quotes when I add the remote and I am using Windows cmd, not git bash. when I put `file://` or `file:///` in front, it gives `'//<username>@<ipaddress>:/C:/gameland.git' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: @PHaZerous To my knowledge, a UNC path ([Git local protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_local_protocol)) does [not support authentication](https://superuser.com/a/344933/141). No need for `username@`. As long as you can access a UNC path (`dir \\server\drive\path`), you can add it as a remote. The `file://` is supported [since Git 2.24](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245916/6309).